# SIM7600CE - How to know when SIM card is registered into network by software

Tags: arduino, iot, gsm

I am trying to set up the SIM7600CE to have it connect to the internet whenever I turn it on with Arduino Mega. I know how to turn it on with software by set the pin D12 to HIGH but I don't know how to read the signal of the NETLIGHT pin to get to know when the NETLIGHT starts to blink, which means the SIM card is registered into network successfully. Is there any way I can read that signal? Or is there any other way I can acknowledge when SIM card is registered into network successfully by software?

edit: I am trying to get the information that my SIM7600 is connected by using AT command. Even though I can send the AT command, I cannot parse the response. The result of the code below turns out that the Serial keeps printing the string "at+csq" constantly. Can anybody help?

```
#define mySerial Serial1
#define PWRKEY 12

void setup() 
{
  digitalWrite(PWRKEY, HIGH);     //Press the boot button
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(500);
  mySerial.begin(115200);
  delay(5000);

  while (1)
  {
    Serial.println("AT+CSQ");     //AT command for Signal quality test
    updateSerial();
    delay(1500);
  }
}

void loop() 
{
  updateSerial();
}

void updateSerial()
{
  delay(500);
   while (Serial.available())
  {
    mySerial.write(Serial.read());
  }
  while (mySerial.available())
   {
    Serial.write(mySerial.read());
     if (Serial.find("+CSQ: "))   //Find the AT+CSQ response
    {
      char c = mySerial.read();   
      if (c != '9')               //check the first digit after "+CSQ: ", +CSQ: 99,99 means not detectable, 
      {
        Serial.println("connected");
        break; 
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Are you avle to send AT commands and parse its responses?

Comment: Hi @RobertoCaboni, yes I can send AT commands but somehow I cannot parse its responses. I have added my code in the original post, could you help me with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem with the same logic. However, I tried to just write and read in the SIM7600 serial, with some printing on the monitor to guide/debug. Plus, I used a connection flag as a condition to break the while loop when the MODEM is connected.

```
#define mySerial Serial1
#define PWRKEY 12

bool connectionFlag = 0; //will be set when connected

void setup() 
{
  digitalWrite(PWRKEY, HIGH);     //Press the boot button
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(500);
  mySerial.begin(115200);
  delay(5000);                    //Give it a little time to initialize

  while (1)
  {
    mySerial.println("AT+CSQ");     //AT command for Signal quality test
    connectionCheck();
    if (connectionFlag ==1) break;
    delay(1500);    
  }
  Serial.println("done");
  mySerial.println("AT+CSQ");       //Get the CSQ response to confirm. 
  updateSerial();
}

void loop() 
{
  updateSerial();
}

void connectionCheck()
{
  delay(500);
  while (mySerial.available())
   {
//    Serial.write(mySerial.read());
     if (mySerial.find("+CSQ: "))   //Find the AT+CSQ response
    {
      Serial.print("initializing\t");
      char c = mySerial.read();   
      if (c != '9')               //check the first digit after "+CSQ: ", +CSQ: 99,99 means not detectable, 
      {
        Serial.println("connected");
        connectionFlag = 1;
        break; 
      }
    }
   }
}

void updateSerial()
{
  delay(500);
  if (mySerial.available())
  {
    Serial.write(mySerial.read());
  }
  if (Serial.available())
  {
    mySerial.write(Serial.read());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the AT manual for the MODEM. Enable all URCs related to network registration, once registered on the network - you will receive a URC that will have information if your SIM was able to register on the network or not.

Comment: Hi @BilalQamar, thank you for your response. I am trying to use the AT command to get that information but some how I cannot read its URC. I have updated my original post with code, could you please help me on that?

Comment: @HungThai8053 sure. Can you try first with a simple AT command and parse for 'OK'. Please make sure that you are sending \r\n with the AT command i.e line feed and carriage return which are a standard for AT commands

Comment: Yea I have tried typing directly AT commands on the Serial and it works fine, there are responses. But for writing them by Serial/mySerial.write (like I did in the post), I could not parse the 'OK' URC from the command 'AT' (I don't know but I have tried both "at" and "at\r\n" and they turned out the same). I used Serial/mySerial.find to get the response. Could you help?

Comment: @HungThai8053 I just had a quick look at your code. Why is the while(1) loop for sending AT command inside the setup() function? Move it to the loop() function plus this also means that your code actually never reaches the loop() function. Additionally, print whatever is being received in char c rather than keeping a check on it. Let me know,thanks

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm putting the while(1) loop in the setup here because I have other stuff for the loop() function that needs the board connected first. And you are correct, it seems never reaches the loop() function. Besides, I have done printing char c on the Serial stream before and it worked fine.

Comment: Your check on the char c is incorrect. The first Param could well be just 9 instead of 99 and that is absolutely fine. You might want to check 2 characters to make sure it works fine. Also, if the printing works fine then I am not sure where the problem is

Comment: Sorry for responding this late as I have been busy with other stuff. I have solved the problem and posted my code below. Sorry, previously I have told you that the printing works fine but the truth was I had to modify the code a bit to make it work (I have changed Serial.println() in the while(1) loop into mySerial.println()). I forgot to tell you that. Anyway, thanks a lot for all your help. Appreciate that.

Comment: All is well that ends well - best of luck :)

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem with one of the AT commands AT printed in serial monitor. I changed how i wired it normally RX to TX. TX to RX IN code example RX is pin 7. TX is pin 8. Now I wired Digital pin 7 on main board (Arduino UNO) to digital pin 7 on sim7600CE-T. And same with digital pin 8 to pin 8 now I get OK in serial monitor. And I also connected a wire from main board GND or negative to negative pin of sim7600ce t. Hope this is helpful.